# Best practices for storing large amounts of serialized data in aspx page to be read in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, deserialization, tridion

Using a CMS, the HTML for our sitemap section on the sitemap page is being generated upon publishing of the sitemap page. So in essence, the sitemap.aspx page is sitting as static HTML on our web servers:

Sitemap.aspx:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home Page</a>
  <li><a href="/etc.aspx">etc</a>
</ul>
```

This is great and all, but we're involved in a crusade for separation of concerns and doing away with server side pre-generated HTML. So the CMS is now generating the JSON data needed to build the sitemap section on the aspx page. So the page is now dynamic with an embedded data source like this:

```
[ { Title: "Home Page", Url: "/" }, { Title: "etc", Url: "/etc.aspx" } ]

<ul>
  <% foreach(var page in Pages) { %>
    <li><a href="<%: page.Url %>"><%: page.Title %></a></il>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

The Challenge here is getting ahold of the data to deserialize it into a strongly typed object.

I have explored:

1. **Inserting the data as a field of the page so it can be read in the code behind:**

> <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   nherits="SiteMapPage" Data="@@SiteTreeData@@"
>   %>

Which renders to:

> <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   nherits="SiteMapPage" Data="{ Large amount of json data }"
>   %>

---

2. **Or also creating a custom user control to wrap the JSON where it can be read in the code behind:**

> <A:JsonTransport runat="server" ID="SiteTreeData">@@SiteTreeData@@
>     </A:JsonTransport>

Which renders to:

> <A:JsonTransport runat="server" ID="SiteTreeData">{ Large amount of json data }
>     </A:JsonTransport>

So that I can grab it in the code behind:

```
    this.Data= container.Controls.OfType<LiteralControl>().FirstOrDefault().Text;
```

---

In either case, I run into an exception when loading the page:

> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): (0): error CS1647: An
>   expression is too long or complex to compile

I believe it's because the rendered json string can be very large; in upwards of 1mb.

So, my question is, what is the best practices/approach/guidance for storing large rendered serialized data in the aspx page so that it can be read and deserialized in the code behind with optimal performance in mind?

Answer (score 0):

ASPX is not meant to be used that way.

The best i can figure out - use what your CMS produces as an XML file, load it in codebehind, cache as necessary and and serve your dynamic pages using that.

```
var xml = @"<ul>
    <li><a href=""/"">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a href=""/etc.aspx"">etc</a></li>
</ul>";

var document = XElement.Parse(xml); // You could use XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/fileName.xml")) as well

this.Pages = document
    .Elements("li")
    .Select(li=>li.Element("a"))
    .Select(el=>new Page{Url = el.Attribute("href").Value, Title = el.Value}).ToList();
```